# SQLite3 foreign key validated incorrectly

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

If I enable foreign key validation I cannot insert proper values, which fit with my foreign key definition. What am I missing here?

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE a (id INTEGER NOT NULL, item TEXT NOT NULL);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER NOT NULL, item TEXT NOT NULL,
                        ref INTEGER REFERENCES a (id));
sqlite> INSERT INTO a VALUES (16, 'test');
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
sqlite> INSERT INTO b VALUES (16, 'test2', 16);
Error: foreign key mismatch - "b" referencing "a"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM a;
16|test
```

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915696), that cites the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes):

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

When you add a UNIQUE constraint to your `a.id` column, the example works:

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> CREATE TABLE a (id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, item TEXT NOT NULL);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER NOT NULL, item TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>   ref INTEGER REFERENCES a(id));
sqlite> INSERT INTO a VALUES (16, 'test');
sqlite> INSERT INTO b VALUES (16, 'test2', 16);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM a;
16|test
sqlite> SELECT * FROM b;
16|test2|16
```