# SQLite Error foreign key mismatch - Stock referencing Variants

Tags: sqlite

When I try delete all from table Products i get the error message in title
SQLite Error 1:

> foreign key mismatch - "Stock" referencing "Variants"

This is my tables definitions

```
CREATE TABLE Products ( Codart TEXT NOT NULL, Descri TEXT NOT NULL,...
CONSTRAINT PK_Products PRIMARY KEY(Codart) )

CREATE TABLE Variants ( Codart TEXT NOT NULL, Codvar TEXT NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PK_Variants PRIMARY KEY(Codart, Codvar), 
CONSTRAINT FK_Products FOREIGN KEY (Codart) REFERENCES Products(Codart) ON DELETE CASCADE )

CREATE TABLE Stock (Year int not null, Codart text NOT NULL, Codvar text NOT NULL, Qty real NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PK_Stock PRIMARY KEY(`Year`,`Codart`,`Codvar`), 
CONSTRAINT FK_Products FOREIGN KEY (Codart) REFERENCES Products(Codart) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
CONSTRAINT FK_Variants FOREIGN KEY (Codvar) REFERENCES Variants(Codvar) ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

Question is when i try to run
"DELETE FROM Products"
i get error above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing this sqlite foreign key mismatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915331/what-is-causing-this-sqlite-foreign-key-mismatch)

Comment: In short, `Stock` has a foreign key constraint to `Variants`, but not to its primary key or another `unique` set of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `Stock`, try

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Variants FOREIGN KEY (Codart,Codvar) REFERENCES Variants(Codart,Codvar) ON DELETE CASCADE
```