# Set two columns as foreign keys references two primary keys in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLALchemy in flask. And I am confused about how to set two columns as foreign keys reference two primary keys.

```py
class Feature(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feature'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sample_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sample.id'), primary_key=True)


class Move(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'move'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    feature_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Feature.id), nullable=False)
    sample_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Feature.sample_id), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('feature_id', 'sample_id'),
    )
```

I've tried several configurations but when I try to insert something I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) foreign key mismatch - "move" referencing "feature"
```

In fact the create statement is wrong:

```sql
CREATE TABLE move (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    feature_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    sample_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (feature_id, sample_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(feature_id) REFERENCES feature (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(sample_id) REFERENCES feature (sample_id)
)
```

The last line should be:

`FOREIGN KEY(feature_id, sample_id) REFERENCES feature (id, sample_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915331/what-is-causing-this-sqlite-foreign-key-mismatch)

The working code is:

```
class Move(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'move'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    feature_id = db.Column(Integer)
    sample_id = db.Column(Integer)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([feature_id, sample_id],
                                           [Feature.id, Feature.sample_id]), {})
```