# Sqlite foreign key mismatch?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I've read question [What is causing this sqlite foreign key mismatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915331/what-is-causing-this-sqlite-foreign-key-mismatch) and understood the referenced foreign keys to be unique, but insertions to table are still throwing foreign key mismatch errors:

```
CREATE TABLE medication (
med_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
med_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
dosage VARCHAR (10)
);    

CREATE TABLE disease (
dis_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
disease_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);    

CREATE TABLE dis_med (
disease_id int NOT NULL, 
medication_id int NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PK_dis_med PRIMARY KEY (disease_id, medication_id), 
CONSTRAINT FK_dis FOREIGN KEY (disease_id) REFERENCES disease (dis_id), 
CONSTRAINT FK_med FOREIGN KEY (medication_id) REFERENCES medication (med_id));

CREATE TABLE user_disease (
user_id REFERENCES user (user_id), 
dis_id REFERENCES disease (dis_id), 
med_id REFERENCES dis_med(medication_id),
CONSTRAINT PK_dis_user PRIMARY KEY (user_id, dis_id)
);
```

Per the list in the question I cited:

- the parent table (medication, disease) exists.
- the parent columns exist
- the child table references all of the primary key columns in the parent table

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Don't put answers into question posts. Don't change the question. Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SQLite Foreign Key Support/3. Required and Suggested Database Indexes](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes):

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table.
> If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively
> subject to a **UNIQUE constraint** or have a UNIQUE index.

With this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_disease (
...........................
med_id REFERENCES dis_med(medication_id),
...........................
);
```

the column `med_id` of `user_disease` references the column `medication_id` of `dis_med`, which is not the `PRIMARY KEY` of `dis_med` and there is no `UNIQUE` constraint for it. It just references `med_id` of `medication` .

Why do you need the column `med_id` in `user_disease`?
You have `dis_id` referencing `disease`, which may also be used to retrieve from `dis_med` (all) the row(s) from `dis_med` for that disease.