# Foreign key mismatch when insert (SQLite)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

So here's my sqlite code..

```
CREATE TABLE "performance" (
    "title" TEXT,
    "date"  date,
    "theaterID" INTEGER,    

PRIMARY KEY("title","date","theaterID"),

    FOREIGN KEY("title") REFERENCES "movies"("title"),
    FOREIGN KEY("theaterID") REFERENCES "theater"("theaterID")
);

CREATE TABLE "reservation" (
    "userName"  TEXT,
    "reservationID" INTEGER auto_increment,
    "date"  date,
    "theaterID" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("userName","reservationID","date","theaterID"),
    FOREIGN KEY("date") REFERENCES "performance"("date"),
    FOREIGN KEY("userName") REFERENCES "user"("userName"),
    FOREIGN KEY("theaterID") REFERENCES "theater"("theaterID")
);
```

And I make following inserts in specific order:

```
INSERT INTO performance(title,date,theaterID) 
VALUES("The Godfather", 20200230, 9);



INSERT INTO reservation(userName,reservationID,date,theaterID)
VALUES("user1", 1 , 20200230, 9);
```

Everything works until I try to insert a reservation. I get the following error:

> "foreign key mismatch error - 'reservation' referencing 'performance'"

I can't seem to find the reason for it? What changes do I have to do?

Comment: I've been sitting here for hours not being able to find the solution.. An answer would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
FOREIGN KEY("date") REFERENCES "performance"("date"),
```

However, the primary key on `performance` has THREE parts:

```
PRIMARY KEY("title", "date", "theaterID"),
```

You need to reference all three -- in the correct order -- in the foreign key declaration:

```
FOREIGN KEY("date") REFERENCES "performance"("title", "date", "theaterID"),
```

However, `"title"` is not in the table, so you have to add that.

OR, just add an auto-incrementing primary key to `"performance"` and use that for the reference.

Also, drop the double quotes.  They just make SQL harder to write and read.  And answers harder to write.

Answer (score 1):

check this post 
[What is causing Foreign Key Mismatch error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208245/what-is-causing-foreign-key-mismatch-error)

Problem could be:

- The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint are not
  the primary key of the parent table and are not subject to a unique
  constraint using collating sequence specified in the CREATE TABLE