# Foreign Key constraint issue

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

What could possibly caused a FK error? I'm inserting an 'Activity' record into a database that has a 'StaffId' field on (FK with Staff table), I've looked for the staffId in question (no white spaces etc.) and it DOES exist. What else can cause an error with a foreign key field?

EDIT: Error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Activities_Staff". The conflict occurred in database
>   "DataWarehouseB", table "dbo.Staff", column 'StaffId'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

Comment: Another relationship, then?  You might post your DDL, code and error.

Comment: Can you show the **exact and complete** error message?? Also: **what*** database and which version??

Comment: See OP. SQLServer 2008 R2. I'm doing this from C# through the use of DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) documentation says

> If the database schema contains foreign key errors that require
>   looking at more than one table definition to identify, then those
>   errors are not detected when the tables are created. Instead, such
>   errors prevent the application from preparing SQL statements that
>   modify the content of the child or parent tables in ways that use the
>   foreign keys. Errors reported when content is changed are "DML errors"
>   and errors reported when the schema is changed are "DDL errors". So,
>   in other words, misconfigured foreign key constraints that require
>   looking at both the child and parent are DML errors. The English
>   language error message for foreign key DML errors is usually "foreign
>   key mismatch" but can also be "no such table" if the parent table does
>   not exist. Foreign key DML errors are may be reported if:
>
> - The parent table does not exist.
> - The parent key columns named in    the foreign key constraint do not exist.
> - The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint are not the primary key of      the parent table and are not subject to a
>     unique constraint using    collating sequence specified in the CREATE
>     TABLE.
> - The child table references the primary key of the parent without specifying the    primary key columns and the number of primary key
>     columns in the    parent do not match the number of child key columns.

Some DBs might also support using a [non-unique index as a foreign key reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588741/can-a-foreign-key-reference-a-non-unique-index),