# Mysql CHECK Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

I am student and now I have to work out what check means.
We've got a little code:

```
CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(PLZ) = 4)
```

Now I have to find out what exactly it is doing. The problem is that I can't find anything in the internet(or i am doing something totaly wrong using google). 
I created this code to test it:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
    ID CHAR(4),
    CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(ID) = 4)
);

INSERT INTO Test(ID) VALUES ('12345');
```

The problem is that I am not able to find any difference wheter I remove the line with the CHECK constraint or not. Now I am asking you? What is the difference wheter I use it or not.