# Representing SQL constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `sold` (
`part_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`date` DATE NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`part_ID`, `date`) ,
 FOREIGN KEY (`part_ID` )
 REFERENCES `part` (`part_ID` );
```

This table represent parts sold each day, constraint says number of sales should be at least 25 and at most 100. How can I implement this constraint?

I think it should start with something like this:

```
CHECK ( NOT EXISTS ...
```

Comment: @AshReva enforcing this constraint: number of sales should be at least 25 and at most 100.

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36413/1822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
CONSTRAINT chk_sales CHECK (columnName>=25 AND columnName <=100)
```

Also refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Comment: There is no column that holds number of sale!!

Comment: Then cant you have it? How will you add constraint then?

Comment: If i knew it, I wouldn't ask!

Comment: then can you add column as i said?

Comment: No. Table can not be altered.

Comment: Which column represent parts sold?

Comment: `part_ID` is the part ID of sold item, and `date` is the day the part is sold.

Comment: When will you check if more than 25 items are sold? Is it during inserting records?

Comment: Anyway, has MySQL already added [full support to check constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247655/mysql-check-constraint/14247690#14247690) yet?

Comment: That will not work. MySQL still doesn't support check constraints.