# CHECK constraint Alternative in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, check-constraints

hi i am trying to use `CHECK` constraint form `MySQL` , i got an example from **w3 schools**.

```
MySQL:

CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CHECK (P_Id>0)
)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

but it is not working as expected , the validation is ignored , after searching some time i found that `The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.`

refrence :- 
[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

then i searched for an answer , then i got this

[Mysql CHECK Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247655/mysql-check-constraint)

**it says that you can use a trigger when insert an update the record , alternatively to the check constraint .**

i have 2 questions .

1.what is the best alternative for `CHECK` constraint in `MySQL`?

2.what is the purpose of only parsing `CHECK` constraint with out using it . why is that exist if it is no use ??

Comment: That's how MySQL works. There are several other places where MySQL silently ignores features it does not support (or silently truncates data which doesn't fit into a column).

Comment: [w3school is complete and utter garbage](http://www.complaintsboard.com/complaints/w3schoolscom-this-website-is-complete-and-utter-garbage-c630826.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the comment , is there any altermatve in mysql to do what check constraint does ??

Comment: "*what is the best alternative for `CHECK` constraint in `MySQL`?*" - [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html), like you already said in your question.  "*what is the purpose of only parsing `CHECK` constraint with out using it . why is that exist if it is no use ??*" - to ensure that SQL-standard DDL will parse without error whilst noone has yet written the code to implement working constraints.

Comment: @eggyal: the behaviour "*parse without error*" is really a bug in my opinion. If a DDL statement was succesfull, everything specified in there should be active. I think MySQL should throw an error that it doesn't support this feature - as every other DBMS does.

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: alternative? Upgrade to Postgres maybe?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't disagree.

Comment: Is it just me or does it look as though P_Id should be an auto-increment field?