# Prevent having a zero value in a mysql field

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (   
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  mynum int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
)
```

The default value for an int is 0 (zero).  In my application, 0 is an invalid value for "mynum".

How can I ensure that a 0 is never entered for mynum?  I can do the check in my application code, but I wish I didn't have to do that.  I want mysql to prevent any insert of value 0 in the mynum field.

Thanks.

Comment: you can define a default value that is not 0

Comment: You have to do it in your application code.  There is no `NOT 0` equivalent to `NOT NULL`. You might also try using a trigger, but your simplest and best bet is to enforce it in application logic.

Comment: This could be done via `TRIGGER`s. I would need more information though as to what you mean by "preventing". Should it change the value to something else, should it fully abort?

Comment: @EdCottrell: well, there is a `NOT 0` equivalent: it's called a check constraint - only MySQL doesn't support it. So it needs to be done in the application and you need to hope that your SQL scripts are all correct.

Comment: Fair enough; I should have specified that there isn't an equivalent in MySQL.  You can [emulate the constraint with triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247655/mysql-check-constraint), but application logic is probably the best bet.

Comment: @skiwi  it should fully abort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL 5.5 with the `SIGNAL` syntax in a `TRIGGER`.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

You can do it then with the following `TRIGGER`:

```
create trigger mytable_zero_check
before insert on my_table
for each row
begin
    if(new.mynum = 0) then
        SIGNAL 'your error message'
    end if 
end
```

If you are running < 5.5, then you can make a syntax error (for example assigning `NULL` to a field that does not allow `NULL`s), and the `INSERT` will be aborted aswell.