# Only 10 inserts per day in table per IP address

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I will have the following table (say a user table) that will contain this data:

id -- (auto increment)

username -- (unique)

password -- (not relevant to question)

IP address -- (only allowed 10 user creations per day)

request_number -- (number of times a single ip address has inserted into the database)

Is there any way to constrain a database to raise an error upon insert if those factors are not met?

I will be coding in PHP and I would HIGHLY prefer that I did not have to perform two queries, or test events in PHP to meet my goals.

I would like to find a way to meet these goals purely in database schema. Is there a way?

(Please no, "why don't you check with php?" That would be slower than a single transaction and I would like to find a way to do it with mysql table schema and raise an exception if my conditions are not met)

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: It would be marginally slower. Create a stored procedure and upon the mentioned condition use `SIGNAL`. PHP will interpret that as an Exception.

Comment: That may be the answer that I have been looking for. I was under the impression that PHP could not interpret exceptions raised by stored procedures. Can you go into  detail in an answer?

Comment: Using PDO, and setting it into Exception mode allows you to catch any database errors as an Exception. The subject is covered on www.php.net/PDO pretty well and popular PHP ORMs (Doctrine, Eloquent, Propel) handle that in a good way. If you have problems finding info on how to do it exactly, line by line of code - I can provide you with complete example, but I believe that nudging people in the right way usually helps more than handing out finished code.

Comment: I would agree.. and my code is already doing that! :) I meant more raising a signal with a stored procedure.. and making it an answer that I can accept. And I wish I could upvote it 10000 times...

Comment: I can't see why id (or possibly username) and/or password would be columns in this table!?!? (or vice versa)

Comment: @N.B. You should post something that I can upvote an accept, regardless of if you want to show working code. I will figure that out

Comment: I'd recommend constraint triggers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247655/mysql-check-constraint

Comment: Both signals and triggers are acceptable. Triggers are marginally faster but in this case will create a race condition, signals and a stored procedure will be a bit slower, but the race condition will not exist. The question then becomes what drawbacks can you live with for the situation :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, and I'm not too keen whether this is of sufficient quality for an answer - using `SIGNAL` will be interpreted as an Exception in PHP (PDO > Exception mode). Using triggers (to check the condition), you can `SIGNAL` and stop the execution (if 10 inserts occurred already). PHP (PDO) will correctly interpret it as an Exception and you can handle error display from there.