# mysql constraint check produces error

Tags: mysql, constraints

For homework we have to craft an sql statement that does quite a few things at once. I'll post it here

ALTER TABLE assn7 ADD gpa float DEFAULT 4.0
CONSTRAINT gpacheck
check(gpa >= 0.0 AND gpa <=4.0);

It should be obvious what I'm trying to do but I get an error

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT gpacheck
check(gpa >= 0.0 AND gpa <=4.0)' at line 2

it works if I take out the constraint check but we need it to be one big sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

your query statement is bit wrong. Per  [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) it should be

```
ALTER TABLE assn7 ADD gpa float DEFAULT 4.0;
ALTER TABLE assn7 ADD CONSTRAINT gpacheck check(gpa >= 0.0 AND gpa <=4.0);
```

You can't mix both adding up a column and constraint together.

Though to point out; there is no `Check` constraint support in MySQL. Per [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) it says

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Alternative, is to go for triggers (`BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`)

Answer (score 0):

Check constraints [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247655/mysql-check-constraint) in MySQL, but you can achieve your statement in one line by adding a comma like this:

```
ALTER TABLE assn7 ADD gpa float DEFAULT 4.0, ADD CONSTRAINT gpacheck check(gpa >= 0.0 AND gpa <=4.0);
```