# How to prevent insertion of reversed two-field primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with two columns `user_x` and `user_y` which is combined into primary key. So now inserting duplicating records like `1,2` and `1,2` is impossible. But how to prevent insertion reversed combinations like `1,2` and `2,1`? Via query that alter table or in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Actually, [the solution provided in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247655/mysql-check-constraint)  is probably better.

Comment: I would argue for a third solution: Deliberately insert both rows, but use a flag to identify the 'true' one.