# MYSQL Error # 1005

Tags: mysql, database

I have been trying to create a foregin key with nbrseats but I i get the error 1005 all the time.
CAn someone help me!?

```
create table theater (
    name varchar(30) primary key,
    nbrseats int not null
) ENGINE=INNODB;

create table reservation (
    nbr integer auto_increment,
    users_username varchar(30),
    cinemashow_showdate date,
    movies varchar(30),
    nbrseats int not null,
    primary key (nbr),
    foreign key (nbrseats) references theater(nbrseats),
    foreign key (users_username) REFERENCES users(username)
        on delete cascade,
    foreign key (cinemashow_showdate, movies) references cinemashow(showdate, movie_title)
       on delete cascade
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: if you do `show engine innodb status`, in the output will be a "last foreign key error" section, which more details why you're getting the 1005.

Comment: can we see users dans cinemashow's structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be a `FOREIGN KEY` in another table, you must have an index created on `theater.nbrseats`.  And in order to be able to reference a specific row reliably, it should therefore be a `UNIQUE` index. Otherwise, if you have duplicate values, the referencing table won't be able to discern which row it references. Even though InnoDB will allow you to create the relationship on a non-unique index, it is likely not the behavior you are looking for.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588741/can-a-foreign-key-reference-a-non-unique-index) for more info on that bit.

```
create table theater (
  name varchar(30) primary key,
  nbrseats int not null,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idx_nbrseats` (nbrseats)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The same will be true of the other `FOREIGN KEY` definitions in your table `reservation`, though we do not see their referenced tables posted here.  The rules are:

- The referenced column must be indexed (independently of any other compound indexes on it)
- The referencing column must have exactly the same data type.

This kind of calls into question your design, however.  If you are attaching a number of seats to a reservation, will the reservation number of seats *exactly* match the number available in the theater? Also this means that you could not have 2 theaters with the same number of seats.

You may need to reconsider your design here, and perhaps create a `FOREIGN KEY` that references `theater.name` instead of `theater.nbrseats`.

Comment: MySQL creates the indexes automatically now, if need be. Of course, OP could be on an ancient version.

Comment: @MarcB Since what version? Testing on a not-so-ancient 5.5.23, the index doesn't get created.

Comment: Ah. D'oh. misreading the docs. it only auto-creates in the referencing table. the target field in the parent able must be indexed manually.

Comment: @MarcB Ah yes, that makes more sense.