# Error code: 1215 : Cannot add foreign key constrain MYSql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I don't really get programming much so sorry if my question looks cliched. I am getting the "Error code: 1215 : Cannot add foreign key constrain MYSql" whenever I try this program

```html
create table department(dept_name varchar(20) primary key,
building varchar(15),
budget numeric(12,2));
create table course(course_id varchar (7),
title varchar (50),
dept_name varchar (20),
credits numeric (2,0),
primary key (course_id),
foreign key (dept_name) references department);
```

Can somebody help me out

Comment: What is the logic of adding a foreign key to the same table which is a primary key ?

Comment: This question has been asked many times here , check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663595/mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined which column of `dept_name` you are referencing. Please try this:

```
create table department(dept_name varchar(20) primary key,
building varchar(15),
budget numeric(12,2));
create table course(course_id varchar (7),
title varchar (50),
dept_name varchar (20),
credits numeric (2,0),
primary key (course_id),
foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name));
```