# How to specify a foreign key property in SQLite-Net Extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite-net-extensions

How do I specify a foreign key that references a specific property instead of the primary key?

For example the Stock class has a uuid property. And I want to create a foreign key in the Valuation class that references it using this property.

In the following example the line [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))] references the ID property of the Stock class, but I need it to reference the UUID property.

How would I do that?

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; } 
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public string StockUUID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What error are you facing or stocked at ?

Comment: [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]  

This references the ID property, but I need to make it reference the UUID property.

Comment: have a look at this might help you out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key)

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I need, but it's useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` always references the `PrimaryKey` of another class. In this case, your `PrimaryKey` is an integer, but you are trying to reference another property of type string. This is not supported, so you either reference the primary key, or you make the `UUID` property primary key.

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string UUID { get; set; } 
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Making the UUID property primary key seems to work fine. I was hoping I would not have to do that as I didn't want to change the existing schema.