# Is it possible to make a foreign key without the field being a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example

```
create table Equipment (

Equipmenttype nvarchar(1,
Description nvarchar(10),
Primary Key (Equipmenttype)
)

Create table Room (

RoomID nvarchar(8),
Capacity numeric(3),
Roomtype(fk,nvarchar(2)

)
```

I want to create the following table...

```
create table RoomEquipment(
(RoomID here)
(Equipmenttype here)
```

but `Equipmenttype` is not a primary key.

Comment: No. You can't create a foreign key to just any column. That doesn't make any logical sense. And of course in your example you state that EquipmentType is the primary key.

Comment: As I see Equipmenttype id PK. RoomID is not PK.

Comment: If you want to do that then you have found a flaw in your database design.

Comment: No pk needed, an alternate key (unique constraint) should work as well.

Comment: any table should contain a PK, already because of the performance of your query's

Answer (score 2):

You can create `foreign key` on columns that are `PK` or `Unuque`:

So you have to create a unique index on `RoomID`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_Room_RoomID ON dbo.Room(RoomID);
```

Now you can create a `foreign key` in table `RoomEquipment`.

Answer (score 2):

A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

Source: [Foreign Key to non-primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key)

Answer (score 0):

`Equipmenttype` **is** a primary key, in its own table `Equipment`, and `RoomID` **should** be a primary key for `Room`.

So `RoomEquipment` is a standard many-to-many relationship table.