# SQL Unique Value With Primary & Foreign Keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, unique, primary-key

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before but using SQL I'm trying to only allow a table to have a unique value using both a primary and foreign keys. This may sound confusing so these are my SQL statements.

`Folder` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Folder] 
(
    [FolderID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FolderURL] NCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [FolderTag] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FolderURL] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([FolderID] ASC)
);
```

`Extension` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Extension] 
(
    [ExtensionID] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [FolderID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LocationURL] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ExtensionID] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [fk_FolderID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([FolderID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Folder]([FolderID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT uc_Extension UNIQUE ([ExtensionID], [FolderID]) 
);
```

In the `Extension` table I would like to have it have a unique value using the `[FolderID] & [ExtensionID]`. I first tried to achieve this by creating a primary key using both values, then I tried the current statement above.

**Edit**

I didn't give enough detail for what I am asking, below is a layout of both tables that i want to create and what the results are using the methods above.

`Folder` Table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| Folder ID |        FolderURL        |  FolderTag       |
|-----------|-------------------------|------------------|
|   Home    | C:/users/test/          | Home Folder      |
| Downloads | E:/Donwloads            | Downloads Folder |
|   Music   | C:/users/test/music     | Music Folder     |
| Documents | C:/users/test/documents | Downloads Folder |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

`Extension` Table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Extension ID | FolderID  |        LocationURL         |
|--------------|-----------|----------------------------|
|    .jpg      | Downloads | C:/users/test/pictures     | = Pass 
|    .png      | Downloads | C:/users/test/pictures     | = Pass
|    .docx     | Documents | C:/users/test/BusinessDocs | = Pass
|    .mp3      |   Home    | C:/users/test/music        | = Pass
|    .jpg      |   Home    | C:/users/test/pictures     | = Fail
|    .mp3      | Downloads | C:/users/test/music        | = Fail
---------------------------------------------------------
```

From the table layouts provided above you can see that the last two fail due to the .mp3 ID is already entered into the table. what I am asking about is the to create a table which has a unique primary key, or something else which will allow for a unique `ExtensionID` and `FolderID` so it will allow the last two values in the `Extension` Table.

If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why were you not able to make both into a primary key?  That is acceptable.

Comment: What is wrong with the current approach? With a UNIQUE constraint on `FolderID,ExtensionID`, you cannot store duplicates into that table...... so basically, this should do exactly what you want - doesn't it??

Comment: I thought that i would be acceptable too but it seems that visual studio doesn't accept it, this could be because of VS, but i don't know. The statement i used for the using both as the primary key was:CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Extension] (
    [ExtensionID]    VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [FolderID] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [LocationURL]    VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ([ExtensionID], [FolderID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([FolderID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Folder]([FolderID])
); But it did seem to work

Comment: You didn't answer my question: with this current approach, with the UNIQUE constraint - are you still able to insert **duplicate data** into your table?? You shouldn't be ....

Comment: You shouldn't be able to add duplicates, with this design. Have you considered switching your PKeys to the ID fields? It is unusual for FKeys to join to a non PKey.  See this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key.

Comment: Edit your question, and paste in SQL INSERT statments that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I made some edits to the question and provided a layout of both tables to show what the current results are if that is any help. and to address marc_s response, it sad to that it will only allow an `ExtensionID` to be entered only once despite the `FolderID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Extension] 
(
    [ExtensionID] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [FolderID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LocationURL] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ([ExtensionID], [FolderID]),

    CONSTRAINT [fk_FolderID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([FolderID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Folder]([FolderID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

---

Here's full code and output. SQLFiddle.com is down for me; this is in PostgreSQL syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE Folder
(
    FolderID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FolderURL NCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FolderTag VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (FolderURL),
    UNIQUE (FolderID)
);

CREATE TABLE Extension 
(
    ExtensionID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FolderID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LocationURL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ExtensionID, FolderID),

    CONSTRAINT fk_FolderID 
        FOREIGN KEY (FolderID)
        REFERENCES Folder(FolderID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

insert into folder values
('Home', 'C:/users/test/', 'Home Folder'),
('Downloads', 'E:/Donwloads', 'Downloads Folder'),
('Music', 'C:/users/test/music', 'Music Folder'),
('Documents', 'C:/users/test/documents', 'Downloads Folder');

insert into Extension values
('.jpg', 'Downloads', 'C:/users/test/pictures'),
('.png', 'Downloads', 'C:/users/test/pictures'),
('.docx', 'Documents', 'C:/users/test/BusinessDocs'),
('.mp3', 'Home', 'C:/users/test/music'),
('.jpg', 'Home', 'C:/users/test/pictures'),
('.mp3', 'Downloads', 'C:/users/test/music');

select * from folder;
```

```
folderid    folderurl                 foldertag
--
Home        C:/users/test/            Home Folder
Downloads   E:/Donwloads              Downloads Folder
Music       C:/users/test/music       Music Folder
Documents   C:/users/test/documents   Downloads Folder
```

```
select * from extension;
```

```
extensionid  folderid    locationurl
--
.jpg         Downloads   C:/users/test/pictures
.png         Downloads   C:/users/test/pictures
.docx         Documents  C:/users/test/BusinessDocs
.mp3         Home        C:/users/test/music
.jpg         Home        C:/users/test/pictures
.mp3         Downloads   C:/users/test/music
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work the way i would like it. I kinda wish i could explain what i would like better.

Comment: *" Doesn't seem to work the way i would like it."* FWIW, that's pretty useless feedback. It works *exactly* like you *said* you wanted. See additional code and output.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information and after wiping the entire DB and testing yours it works the way i need i too thanks.