# Create a Foreign Key from an attribute that is not Primary Key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, rdbms

Is it possible to create a foreign key - FK in one table which will refer to a normal atribute (not Primary Key - PK) in another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are working in a [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system):

Yes, you can. But **ONLY** if values of the FK destination field are unique.

The column pointed from the FK **MUST** have unique values to keep [database referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) safe.

A way to assure so is defining a [Unique Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on it.

*Edited to clarify:*

`Table A` has a FK column pointing to `table B`, column named `B_anycolumn`.

There's no actual need to `B_anycolumn` from being PK from `table B`, but it must have a Unique Constraint to ensure that all values in it are different.

Even though this is possible, normal relationships between tables are to PK columns, since are always unique by definition.

Comment: Ok, so if i understood, the normal atribute that i want to refer to cannot have duplicated values. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

refer this:

[Foreign Key to non-primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key)

Comment: Thank you for you response!