# How can I implement a language system in my mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a video player application with php and mysql.

The application has videos that are gathered in playlists like this:

Playlists table:

```
+----+------------------+------+
| id | name             | lang |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | Introduction     |   1  |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Videos table:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | name         | playlist_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | Video1       |           1 |
|  2 | Video2       |           1 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

It worked fine until now, because I need to build a searcher that finds videos depending on its name and language.

I though of creating another field called `lang` in the videos table, but then I realize that this maybe would contradict the normalization database rules. Because I would be repeating unnecessary information.

What can I do to select the videos without creating another field? Or do I need to create a new one with the repeated information?

**EDIT:**
JOIN LEFT both tables is not a solution, because I maybe add in the future a new table that links to playlists such as courses.

Comment: What do you mean "repeating unnecessary information"...you need to search by lang, so how would adding lang to this table repeat unnecessary information?

Comment: The videos lang field would have the same value as the playlist lang field.

Comment: `JOIN` the playlists and videos table to get all fields you need?

Comment: I thought about it, but if I add a new table called `courses` that relates to playlists for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `LANGUAGE_ID` COLUMN in `Videos` table,which will foreign key references to  `Playlists.lang` .

Try above solution.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. The video's language ID doesn't refer to a playlist -- it refers to a language.

Comment: @duskwuff if we make relationship between `Playlists.lang` = `Videos.LANGUAGE_ID ` then it is possible to achieve expected business logic.

Comment: @XavierCarreraGimbert Exactly..!!

Comment: @duskwuff The playlists and the videos within have the same language

Comment: @SagarGangwal ,(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key#18435114) but a foreign key can only refer to a primary key. How can I do it if `Playlists.lang` is not a primary key?

Comment: @XavierCarreraGimbert So if possible then create `unique key` or `Primery key` on `Playlists.lang `

Comment: @SagarGangwal That would make it impossible to have any two playlists with the same language. That's clearly not intended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about what attribute you want to assign to which entity (playlist, video or possibly course). You can assign language ids to both, playlist and video list items independently. Who is to say that you are not allowed to include a video with a language id of 2 in a playlist that carries a language id of 1? (This could, for example be a video in a foreign language that you *want* to appear in a playlist of your own language).

To search for suitable items you should then definitely use some kind of `join` (`on video.playlist_id=playlist.id`). The resulting table will contain both, `video.language_id` and `playlist.language_id`, which is *not* a case of having redundant information, as I have tried to explain above since they refer to different entities.

Comment: Excellent explanation!! Thanks