# SQL wont allow me to add foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a question and answer site and for linking the user accounts to the questions I want to have the username from the login table be a foreign key of the questions table so when a user asks a question it must be linked to his or her username.  Can I not have foreign key's that are varchar datatype?  Or must the foreign key be only a primary key of another table?  The error I'm getting says 'Key column "'username' doesn't exist in table" .  What am I doing wrong?

```
create table login (user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username 
varchar (100), password varchar (100), primary key (user_id));

create table questions (q_id int not null auto_increment, question 
varchar (100), primary key (q_id), foreign key (username) references 
login (username));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
create table login (username 
varchar (100), password varchar (100), primary key (username));

create table questions (q_id int not null auto_increment, question 
varchar (100), primary key (q_id), username varchar(100),foreign key (username) references 
login (username)); 

create table answers (a_id int not null auto_increment, answer varchar (100), primary key (a_id), q_id int, foreign key (q_id) references questions (q_id));
```

I tested it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ec2a

You need to:

```
1) Make Login.UserName unique
2) Declare UserName in the questions table
```

Comment: yes thank you I think this solve the problem because I also have an answer table that the q_id is a foreign key of.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if it has helped you the most.  Let me know if anything needs to be clarified.

Comment: I'm new to this site and would give you a point if I could but they wont let me.  I'll figure out how to say answerd though becasue this did work and I thank you!  one more question though.  now I'm trying to get my answers table but it's not working.  It worked when I did it like this before but not now.  see anything wrong?

Comment: create table answers (a_id int not null auto_increment, answer varchar (100), primary key (a_id), foreign key (q_id) references questions (q_id));

Comment: @do734, I have added your answers table to my answer.  Let me know it works - I was unable to test it as SQLFiddle appears to be down.

Comment: Sorry was away and just got back.  It works!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, Foreign Key is a **Key** and should expect to be linked with another **Key**. Now, `username` is simple column in one table, then how it can be **key** column for another table ?

The purpose of Foreign key is to show the relationship between the tables. You **MUST** have same column in both the table, which you are going relate.

Comment: Ok thank you.  So if I'm understanding correctly a foreign key needs to be linked to a primary key only meaning I should take a different approach to linking the username and q_id right?   Or is there a way to do what I'm attempting to do?

Comment: No, It must link with **key** column  and that can be even **unique key**

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. Your Questions table does not have a username column. It must. Even then it would not work because of problem 2.
2. As a general rule, your foreign key reference needs to use the user_id and not the username. The reason is that Fk references generally start from a column and end in a primary key value.

   create table questions (q_id int not null auto_increment, user_id int not   null, question varchar (100), primary key (q_id), foreign key (user_id) references login (user_id));

Here is a more elaborate elaboration from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key):

Answer (score 0):

> The correct way is,

```
create table login (user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username 
varchar (100), password varchar (100), primary key (user_id));

create table questions (q_id int not null auto_increment, question 
varchar (100), primary key (q_id), foreign key (user_id) references 
login (user_id));
```