# Composite key =[foreign key+primary key]

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller

1st Table = Student [s_id is pk ]

2nd table = Teacher[t_id is pk , s_id is f_k]  here i want to create composite key[comp_id] combining  (t_id[pk] + s_id[f_k])

and that composite key use as foreign key to collage table

3rd table= collage[col_id is pk, comp_id as f_k  ]

how to do in using  J_PA repository and spring boot m_v_c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key to non-primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: i want to create composite key[ck] =[pk+fk].........................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That design would make your `Teacher` table Many-to-many, which you should normalise like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #Student
(
    id INT -- student
)

CREATE TABLE #Teacher
(
    id INT -- teacher
)

CREATE TABLE #TeacherStudent
(
    id INT,   -- optional
    t_id INT, -- teacher
    s_id INT  -- student
)
```

You could create an `id` on the `TeacherStudent` table or create a composite key from the other id's you have in that table.