# Many to Many relationship between two Dimensions and Fact

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a request for an attribute in a dimension that has a many-to-many relationship with another  dimension.

Here is the case:

- Dimension 1: Employee
- Dimension 2: Nationality

I have 2 source tables :

- Employee
- Nationality

One employee can have multiple Nationalities codes. Each Nationality has an ID(code) and a label. A Nationality can belong to many employees.

In my data model the Fact is linked with the Employee and it's recording every change made to some specific fields of the Employee (and other dimensions).

Is it possible to use **Bridge Table Method** between Employee Dimension and Nationality Dimension and link only the Employee Dimension to my Fact ? If yes, how should I implement this method?

Comment: Can you simply do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948195/composite-key-foreign-keyprimary-key/46948431#46948431

Comment: You have a fact table that has employee ID and Nationality ID? I don't think it'll work right if you only link Employee dim to your fact, it would have to be the bridge table.