# Laravel 5.3 Migration: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, database-migration

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to create  FK, however when I migrate my table using artisan I'm getting the following error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `topic_video` add constraint `topic_video_vendor_id_foreign` foreign key (`vendor_id`) references `vendors` (`id`))



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I have tried multiple solutions on SOF for different laravel versions but none of them work.

This is my topic_video table (InnoDB)

[image]

This is an old and big project, as I don't have migrations for it, only for new tables we have migrations. So I have created a vendors (MyISAM)

```
Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('channel_url');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Then I have add FK of above migration to topic_video table.

```
Schema::table('topic_video', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('vendor_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors');
        });
```

I have tried without unsigned(), without nullable() but still didn't work! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you sure the vendors 's migration comes before topic_video migration in  your migrations folder?

Comment: topic_video deosn't have a migration, it was created through database long time ago approx 10 years. As i have mentioned, only the new tables which we are creating in future has migration, Today i have created vendors folders migration and added it, then tried to created topic_video migration for foreign key above.

Comment: and my topic_video migration for adding fk comes after vendors table creation migration

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('topic_video', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('vendor_id')->unsigned()
    });
    Schema::table('topic_video', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors');
    });
}
```

and make sure the vendors migration create is before the topic_video migration create

Comment: topic_video table already has id `$table->increments('id');` which is primary key and it has thousands of records too.

Comment: count you provide the full list of columns for both tables

Comment: I have already provided above, see the screenshot of topic_video table above, migration is already provided for vendors table as well.

Comment: This sol was already tried, but it didn't work and vendors migrations comes before topic_video

Answer (score 0):

i think i have found the problem ...

If you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, it MUST be a column that has a unique constraint on it.

so you must add 'unique' constraint on

```
$table->integer('vendor_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->unique();
```

please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435114/10573560

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175464(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Basically I am adding vendor's id as FK to topic_video, why do i have to change anything in topic_video's PK ?

Comment: finally ,... i have updated my answer , please check it