# When i inserted data, it always says that foreign key mismatch.I can't find the reason for it?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    Registration_No INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    NIC  varchar(25),
    Student_Name varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    Home_Telephone_No varchar(25),
    Mobile_Telephone_No varchar(25),
    Email varchar(255),
    Education varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (Registration_No, NIC)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment 
(
    Registration_No INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Registration_fee decimal(15,2),
    Annual_subscription decimal(15,2),

    FOREIGN KEY(Registration_No) 
        REFERENCES Student(Registration_No)
);
```

Error:

> Foreign key mismatch - "Payment" referencing "Student" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC25t.png):][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC25t.png)INSERT INTO Payment(Registration_No,Registration_fee,Annual_subscription )VALUES(10,100.50,500);
>
> Foreign key mismatch - "Payment" referencing "Student"

Comment: A FK has to be able to point to a unique record in a different table. That's why you have to point to a PK or UNIQUE constraint column.  For the same reason you cannot point to *part* of a PK, it is not identifiable enough. The PK of `Student` is `Registration_No,NIC`, so you have to point to both attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- your primary key in table `Student` is not `Registration_No` **alone** but **combination** of `Registration_No` and `NIC`
- now when you are referring it from other table you have referred only **PART** of the combination which is **not unique** causing the error, the solution is to **match the FK to PK** or at least **a unique column of parent table** for it to work as expected, read more here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435114/8057127