# Issue while creating FK reference in EF with a code-first approach

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Error**:

> Constraint "FK_DestinationsLists_Regions_AirportCode" of relation "DestinationsLists" does not exist

I am working an ASP.NET Core project. I faced this issue while updating database after add a new migration.

I have three tables:

1. DestinationsList
2. Regions
3. Flights

Now I want to add a FK for `Flights`; `DestinationsList` and `Flights` have a one-to-many relationship. For `Flight` table, `ArrivalAirportCode` is the foreign key column.

I try to add foreign key for `ArrivalAirportCode` from `DestinationsList` table. But EF took FK from Regions. Why?

```
public class DestinationsList
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string AirportCode { get; private set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AirportCode { get; set; }
    public string AirportShortCode { get; set; }
    public DestinationsList DestinationsLists { get; set; }
}

public class Flight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ArrivalAirportCode { get; set; }
    public DestinationsList ArrivalAirport { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public DbSet<DestinationsList> DestinationsLists { get; set; }
public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
public DbSet<Flight> Flight { get; set; }

builder.Entity<DestinationsList>()
                .HasOne(i => i.Region)
                .WithOne(i => i.DestinationsLists)
                .HasPrincipalKey<Region>(i => i.AirportShortCode)
                .HasForeignKey<DestinationsList>(i => i.AirportCode);   // This is already there

builder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(x => x.ArrivalAirport)
                .WithMany(x => x.Flights)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArrivalAirportCode)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.AirportCode);             // This one I tried newly for add FK to Flights
```

Comment: AirportCode is not a valid foreign key, they foreign key should the primary from the related table (ID)

Comment: Foreign key should be unique from related table. Is it? no need to should be a primary key? Am not right?

Comment: Based on you code AirportShortCode  is NOT a key. edit: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435065/foreign-key-to-non-primary-key