# How to Add the foreign key

Tags: mysql

Table One:

```
CREATE TABLE `environment` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `APPLICATION` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `APPLICATION_ID` varchar(42) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`APPLICATION`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Table Two:

```
CREATE TABLE `properties_files` (
  `FILE_NAME` varchar(254) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `APPLICATION` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
   KEY `fk_PROPERTIES_FILES_ENVIRONMENT` (`APPLICATION`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_PROPERTIES_FILES_ENVIRONMENT` FOREIGN KEY (`APPLICATION`) REFERENCES `ENVIRONMENT` (`APPLICATION`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Now My requirement is how to set the foreign key in table two properties_files column name is Application.

Could you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the same structure (data types) of the referenced columns (in this situation you have to decide on:

- `varchar(5)` or `varchar(10)`
- `NOT NULL` or `COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL`

This is just a starting point, you also have to "mark" referenced column as a key/index/unique index. Please refer to this answer for details:
[Can a foreign key reference a non-unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588741/can-a-foreign-key-reference-a-non-unique-index)

Which means you need to add something like that in your `ENVIRONMENT` table:

```
KEY YOUR_KEY_OR_INDEX_NAME(APPLICATION)
```

Added working example here:

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e1e90)

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key column properties are different in master and child, please use below syntax.

Also index is missing on referenced column.

```
CREATE TABLE environment (  ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  APPLICATION VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,  APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(42) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID,APPLICATION), KEY idx_ap(APPLICATION) ) ENGINE=INNODB

CREATE TABLE properties_files (  FILE_NAME VARCHAR(254) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,  APPLICATION VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, KEY fk_PROPERTIES_FILES_ENVIRONMENT (APPLICATION), CONSTRAINT fk_PROPERTIES_FILES_ENVIRONMENT FOREIGN KEY (APPLICATION) REFERENCES ENVIRONMENT (APPLICATION) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Comment: Hi Zafar, Your Your code is working for me Thanks lot. Could you please guide me how to learn the character set and collation ? there is any documentation ?

Comment: If it worked for you then you may choose it as accepted answer.  :)

Comment: @viswa  Please look at this link and take note of the green tick: http://stackoverflow.com/tour