# Referenced column undefined was not found in entity PostsEntity

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to set a n-1 relation between 2 tables using NestJS and TypeORM, but I get this: `Referenced column undefined was not found in entity PostsEntity`. I can't get why and I don't find any post on the Internet related to this error.

My entities:

```
@Entity('appreciations')
export class AppreciationsEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    postId: number;

    @Column()
    userId: number;

    @Column()
    value: boolean;

    @ManyToOne(type => PostsEntity)
    @JoinColumn([
        { name: 'postId' },
        { name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'userId' }
    ])
    post: PostsEntity;
}

@Entity('posts')
export class PostsEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    content: string;

    @Column()
    userId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => UsersEntity, user => user.posts)
    user: UsersEntity;

    @OneToMany(type => AppreciationsEntity, appreciation => appreciation.post)
    @JoinColumn()
    appreciations: AppreciationsEntity[];
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here.

## JoinColumn

First of all, the JoinColumn is incorrect

Normally, the referenced column defaults to the primary column of the related entity.

From [TypeORM doc:](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md)

> By default your relation always refers to the primary column of the related entity.

However, it is not the case when using multiple columns: the referenced column name must be provided.

So instead of this:

```
@ManyToOne(type => PostsEntity)
@JoinColumn([
    { name: 'postId' }, // I expected referencedColumnName to default to 'id'
    { name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'userId' }
])
post: PostsEntity;
```

I should have this:

```
@ManyToOne(type => PostsEntity)
@JoinColumn([
    { name: 'postId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    { name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'userId' }
])
post: PostsEntity;
```

## Index

Creating a foreign key requires the targetted columns on the related entity to have an index.

From [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597886/8993709):

> When you define a foreign key, MySQL requires that an index exists on the column(s) in the remote table

There is no index that contains both the primary key `id` and the column `userId`, hence I must provide it:

```
@Entity('posts')
@Index(['id', 'userId'])
export class PostsEntity {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TypeORM can't find the userId property on your PostsEntity entity.
Regarding to it's documentation [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md) about column relations it should be like this on AppreciationsEntity:

```
@ManyToOne(
  (): ObjectType<PostsEntity> => PostsEntity,
  ({ appreciations }): AppreciationsEntity[] => appreciations,
)
@JoinColumn([
  { name: 'postId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  { name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'userId' },
])
post: PostsEntity;
```

and on PostsEntity should be like this:

```
@OneToMany(
  (): ObjectType<AppreciationsEntity> => AppreciationsEntity,
  ({ post }): PostsEntity => post,
)
appreciations: AppreciationsEntity[];
```