# Can't add foreign key in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, sequelpro

Trying to create a simple relation between two fields in two tables - 'Task' table with the field 'USER_TOKEN' and the 'USER' table with the field 'TOKEN'. The two fields are the same structure. As you can see the error and other things that may assist you to help me understand the problem and fix it.

> System: MacOS 10.12.3 | DB : MySQL 5.7.17 | DBM : Sequel Pro
>
> Error : MySQL said: Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE `TASK` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_TOKEN` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `USER` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TOKEN` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE USER
ADD CONSTRAINT TOKENS
FOREIGN KEY (`TOKEN`) REFERENCES `category`(`USER_TOKEN`)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that tries to add the foreign key?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I add the code right now.

Comment: Where is the `category` table?

Comment: In the `category` table, make sure you have an index on the `USER_TOKEN` column. But usually foreign keys reference the primary key of another table.

Comment: So I only can reference to primary key on the other table ?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that this is usually how foreign keys are used, but it's not required. All that it requires is that the column in the other table has an index, it doesn't have to be the primary key.

Comment: The referenced column should be at least UNIQUE. That is not required by MySQL. But it's required by SQL standard and by the logic of relations.

Comment: We need to know what `category` looks like, asaproG. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: Also, read through [this manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and ensure you're abiding by all the criteria.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The category is the same as TASK table

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you are right the problem was with the UNIQUE the fields not be UNIQUE

Comment: @asaproG: Show that, in the question. Present your [MCVE].

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, it MUST be a column that has a `unique` constraint on it.

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

So your `USER_TOKEN` column of table `TASK` and `TOKEN` column of `USER` table must be `UNIQUE`. So run the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE `TASK` (
`ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`USER_TOKEN` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `USER` (
`ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`TOKEN` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `USER`
ADD CONSTRAINT `TOKENS`
FOREIGN KEY (`TOKEN`) REFERENCES `TASK`(`USER_TOKEN`);
```

Check [Demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/670af3)

Comment: I try this but I get an error - "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Comment: Randomly changing which table you're trying to reference is likely to make things worse, not better.

Comment: I have change the answer check now

Comment: _"If you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, it MUST be a column that has a unique constraint on it."_ Where MySQL is concerned, this is only true for the `NDB` engine. The OP is using InnoDB, for which this is not true. Any compatible index will do. Read [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (However, I would advise a `UNIQUE` index anyway, as does the linked manual page)

Comment: [Can a foreign key reference a non-unique index?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179372/2151290)