# Foreign Constraint is incorrectly formed issue (laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm hitting a bug where I can't run some laravel migrations as I'm getting the error `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

I have read around the subject and can't seem to work out what my problem is. The foreign key I wish to set is an unsigned integer. The data-types are the same across both tables, etc.

Here is my migration:

```
  Schema::create('sample_migration', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('1');
        $table->string('2');
        $table->integer('3');
        $table->string('4');
        $table->integer('5');
        $table->integer('type')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('type')->references('subject_type')->on('some_table');
    });
```

On `some_table` I have `subject_type` as an unsigned integer. Both use the same collation and encoding.

If I add a `unique()` flag on the relevant fields then the migration runs smoothly, but I don't want this as there will be duplicate data.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Read up on the conditions for creating foreign keys here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon - I think that I match all of those criteria. This should just be a very simple operation and I have done this with Laravel many times in the past. I am using the same data type, the same length, ensuring integers are unsigned, etc. It runs if the field has the `unique()` flag set, but not otherwise...

Comment: Do both tables use the `InnoDB` engine? Can you post the migration of `some_table`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to add a foreign key to a non-unique column.

There are 2 ways you can solve this depending on your business logic.

Firstly you can opt to create a unique key on multiple columns and reference the same on `sample_migration` table.

Secondly you can make `subject_type` column as an index key like this

```
$table->integer('subject_type')->unsigned()->index();
```

This method still have foreign key to non unique column which I personally  don't recommend as it may have bad consequences as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179372/3929188