# Does specifying a foreign key make it an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T with a primary key id and foreign key f.  Is f automatically indexed when it is specified as a foreign key? Do I need explicitly add an index for f ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No index is created so yes, you need add explicitly add an index.

**Edited to add...**
I probably ought to add that the source table/column for the data in table T must have a unique index. If you try and make an FK to a column that isn't a unique index (either as a PK or with a UNIQUE constraint), the FK can't be created.

Comment: Just wanted to add, you need these indexes most of the time for performance when you join the parent and child tables. It should be a routine part of creating your foreign key to also create the index at that time unless there is a compelling reason not to. I can think of very few times when I would not want an index on a foreign key field.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is a constraint, not an index.

see [Are foreign keys indexed automatically in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278982/are-foreign-keys-indexed-automatically-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

In case of the foreign key constraint, the foreign key f in table T would be a primary key in the referenced table say T2. In SQL Server a clustered index would be automatically created when T2 got created.

cheers